# Div Style from css file not recognized

Tags: html, css

I have the following `html`, where I center the `div` container on the page with `style`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.18/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.18/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design.css">
    <!-- Load d3.js -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-geo-projection.v2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" defer src=WorldMap.js></script>
</head>
<body>

<div name="input" class="dateContainer" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 656px; text-align: center;">
    <select id="dropdown"></select>
    From: <input type="date" min= "2018-01-01" max="2018-12-30" value="2018-07-22" id="dateFrom">
    To: <input type="date" min= "01-01-2018" max="30-12-2018" value="22-07-2018" id="dateTo">
    <button id="submit">Load</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This works. However If I try to center the `div` with an external `css` file nothing happens:

```
*,*:after,*:before{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  background: lightblue;
  min-height: 100vh;
}


.dateContainer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  width: 656px;
}
```

Whats the reason for this?

Comment: Two possible issues: it is either overwritten by something else or you have cached an older version of your css file. Open your inspector and check if the rules you want are there (so you know whether it is loaded) and if they are, whether they are overwritten

Comment: It was the cache. Could you post this as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When having issues like this you should start by checking two things:

First whether the css file that is being loaded actually includes your rules, because your browser may have a cached version stored and simply avoids loading it again.

If that is ok, then you should check whether or not your rules are being overwritten by any other rule included, that may be more specific or flagged as`!important`

The web inspector can help in both cases!